# Angular 6 - Show loading message when parent component gets the data for its child component

Tags: angular, parent-child

I have a parent component that gets the data from the service. It iterates over the response data for each data it creates the child component by passing the data via @Input. User can do the filter in parent component, so in this time when parent component gets the data from the service all child component should show loading message. 
What is the best way to do this!

Comment: same `@input() isLoading;` and pass this from parent.

Answer (score 0):

A possible (not the simpliest, but easy to understand, and then refactor) solution:

- Create a loading service, which has an eventEmitter object, e.g.: `loadingEventEmitter`
- Inject this service to the child components. Use `*ngIf` to hide and show a loading screen, based on a boolean value, e.g.: `showLoading`
- In your componennts, subscribe to the event emitter object from the service. If the `LoadingEvent` fires, you turn the `showLoading` boolean value to the emitted value. 
  something like this: `this.loadingService.loadingEventEmitter.subscribe( value => this.showLoading = value );`
- Inject this service to the parent component you mention. Fire the emitters when needed with `this.loadingService.loadingEventEmitter.emit(true)` when you start the load and `.emit(false)` when you finish it.

Comment: can i put eventEmitter object in the same service that is used by the parent component to get the data from the server.

Comment: sure, it's up to you. But segregating functions into different services is considered a [clean code](https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-write-clean-code-lessons-learnt-from-the-clean-code-robert-c-martin-9ffc7aef870c) practice.

Comment: `import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoaderService {

    private isLoading$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    currentState = this.isLoading$.asObservable(); 

   constructor() { }

    show() {
        debugger;
        this.isLoading$.next(true);
    }
    hide() {
        debugger;
        this.isLoading$.next(false);
    }
}`

Comment: i created this service, and i m calling the show() in the parent component before doing the http call. and hide on complete of the subscribe. i subscribed in child component by this.loader.currentState.subscribe((is_loading:boolean). Problem is i am not getting the updated data in child component  when show and hide method is invoked.

Comment: It is hard to tell from just a comment, what is wrong - can you please create a tackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular example of your problem instead, with a minimal example of how you want your program to work? I can help you directly with the code then.

Comment: is this problem still persist?